# Pass a method as an argument in a function

Tags: python, pandas, function, methods

I want to pass a pandas method as an argument in a function. For example:

```
def myfunction(dataframe, method):
    return dataframe.method
```

I tried passing min() for example but that doesn't work. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
def myfunction(dataframe, method):
    return getattr(dataframe, method)()
```

example:

```
myfunction(pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3]}), 'min')
```

If you want the **method** and not the output of the method call:

```
def myfunction(dataframe, method):
    return getattr(dataframe, method)
```

example:

```
m = myfunction(pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3]}), 'min')

# then call
m()
```

output:

```
a    1
dtype: int64
```